# Ionic black screen on "ionic serve --lab"

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic v3. When I put in terminal `ionic serve --lab` this opens Google Chrome, but a blank black page appears, with an error in the console like this:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8200/build/app/app.jcrhwwkm.js:1`

[image]

Comment: Did you check the terminal for any build errors?

Comment: I had exactly the same issue on ionic v4. In my case simply clearing the browser cache and reloading solved the issue. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I had same error a few weeks ago,
Solution is,
- Go to project-folder/node_modules/@ionic/lab/www/build/app and rename app.qazxsw.js file to app.jcrhwwkm.js. 
It works for me. It causes of different node modules installing.

Answer (score 0):

**ionic serve --lab** sometimes doesn´t work while you have **ionic serve** open in your browser, close Desktop App first then write lab command again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to nodemodules > @ionic > lab > www > build > app 
Try renaming a file which is starting as app.785432.js or something like that to app.jcrhwwkm.js and reload your browser. 
It will be located just before or after app.registry.json 
In ionic 4 every new app will give this error.

Answer (score -1):

try running `npm i @ionic/lab@npm`